# What is the name given to a value that is inside a variable?

Tags: python, variables, tuples

as someone who just learned the python basics, this might be a weird and stupid question but I got confused.

```
a = (1,2,3)  #if people call this a tuple
b = [1,2,3]  #this as a list
c = 1,2,3    #this as a tuple
d = 1        #then what do people call this? a normal value inside a variable?
```

Also, please correct me if there's mistake, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's called an [`integer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex). You can check the type with `type(1)` or `type(d)`

Comment: (It's not a stupid question IMHO.) In that case, it's a number of some kind. In another case, it might be a string, or a boolean. More generally, it's a *single value* (where the others are structures that can store multiple values).

Comment: mmm... an Integer?

Comment: The generic name for *single* values is *scalar*. Here `d` is an integer scalar, while `a` and `c` are tuples of integers and `b` is list of integers. But beware, elements of a container need not share a common type...

Comment: @Guy - `a`, `b`, and `c` are also variables. The question is what's (conceptually) *in* the variable.

Comment: @SergeBallesta and T.J. Crowder, thank you for the explanation!! It really cleared the question

Answer (score 0):

```
d = 1
```

Since you just put a number, 1 being the number, the variable type is an integer. Python putting a decimal number is a float.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused by the assignment form in this case.
The left hand side is the name you want to assign to and the right hand side
is a value, e.g. `a = 1`, `a` is the name and `1` is the value.

Therefore `(1,2,3)` is a tuple and `a` is tuple after you have
assigned `a = (1,2,3)`. The same holds for any other data-type; lists, integers, floats and so on.

It's nice to think of variables (the left hand side) as values but they are
not. They are not boxes with values inside either but it may help when
reasoning about code.

If you need to talk about it in prose you can say that "the a variable's value is ..." because a variable always refers to a value when it is assigned.